# Xamarin timer function calling which updates 10 textviews depending on current time

Tags: c#, timer, xamarin

I've written a simple schedule app which calculates 10 nearest scheduled bus arrivals depending on current time, and displays them in 10 textViews. Now what I need is to have the whole process repeat over and over every second and refresh the data.

Below is the class that is loaded after this delegate:

```
button1.Click += delegate 
{
 StartActivity(typeof(Schedule));
 FullSchedule.MMain("route1_1_0"); 
};

namespace AndroidApplication7
{
    [Activity(Label = "My Activity")]
    public class Schedule : Activity
    {
        public System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);    

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Schedule);

            TextView textView0 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView0);
            TextView textView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            TextView textView2 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            TextView textView3 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            TextView textView4 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView4);
            TextView textView5 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView5);
            TextView textView6 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView6);
            TextView textView7 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView7);
            TextView textView8 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView8);
            TextView textView9 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView9);
            TextView textView10 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView10);

            textView1.Text = FullSchedule.T[0];
            textView2.Text = FullSchedule.T[1];
            textView3.Text = FullSchedule.T[2];
            textView4.Text = FullSchedule.T[3];
            textView5.Text = FullSchedule.T[4];
            textView6.Text = FullSchedule.T[5];
            textView7.Text = FullSchedule.T[6];
            textView8.Text = FullSchedule.T[7];
            textView9.Text = FullSchedule.T[8];
            textView10.Text = FullSchedule.T[9];

            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            _timer.Enabled = true;        
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() => FullSchedule.MMain(FullSchedule.nname));
            RunOnUiThread(() => StartActivity(typeof(Schedule)));        
        }
    }
}
```

But there are two problems:

1. Every second it updates the view slews from the side as if it was opened (quite logical but I'm not quite sure of a different way of doing it).
2. After 5-10 seconds the app freezes and the screen is just blank.

I'll really appreciate any suggestions to how this updating can be accomplished.

Dmetrey.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a new activity on every timer interval, but at no point do you call Finish().  So you create an activity.  1 second later you create a second.  1 second later both activities create another one (4 activities total), 1 second later 8 activities, etc.  Do you mean to do this?

Comment: Ah thank you i understand now, im just still new to Xamarin, ive make a new function wich gets called from the OnTimedEvent and updates the textviews smooth now, thankyou.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the ticket as answered (the big green tick) if this has solved your problem.